# memory viewer, padding values

Tags: c++

I'm trying to dump some memory values through an injected module in a target process.

```
uintptr_t moduleBase = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

if (fout) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        std::cout << std::uppercase << std::hex << moduleBase + i << ": ";

        unsigned int c = ((int*)(moduleBase))[i];
        std::cout << std::uppercase << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << SwapEndians(c) << " ";

        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

fout.close();
```

I get  the following output:

[image]

I'm trying to get this output:

[image]

Comment: Have you read about how pointer arithmetic works? It's a good idea if you're going to use it.

Comment: Long time ago, a little rusty in C++. Thanks I'll catch up on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to iterate over the bytes that make up the value returned by `SwapEndians(c)` and print them one by one. A function template can be used for that.

```
template <typename T>
void writeBytes(std::ostream& out, T t)
{
   out << std::uppercase << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
   uint8_t* bp = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&t);
   uint8_t* end = bp + sizeof(T);
   for ( ; bp != end; ++bp )
   {
      out << std::setw(2) << int(*bp) << " ";
   }
}
```

You can use it from the other function as:

```
writeBytes(std::cout, SwapEndians(c));
```